# How can we separate multiple string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How can we separate "a","b","c","d" into a, b, c, d in Oracle?

Originally I was using REGEXP_SUBSTR('a;b;c;d','[^;]+',1,level) to separate the value by delimiter semicolon ";", but there is a case where the value itself contains the delimiter semicolon and it causes no records found error

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you have, and what you want to get. The way you put it, you'd just *remove* double quotes from `"a","b","c","d"` to get `a, b, c, d` but that's probably not the case regarding the next paragraph which suggests that you want to split comma-delimited string into rows. You mentioned a **semi-colon**, but - there's none in `"a","b","c","d"` so maybe you meant to say (use?) a **comma** character instead. Shortly: could you edit the question and post proper test case so that we'd see what EXACTLY you have and result you'd want to get from such a source data?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is JSON compatible (where quotes inside literals are escaped with a backslash and literals are comma-separated) then use `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT j.value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         '[' || t.list  || ']',
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS
           value VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$'
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(list VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO table_name (list) VALUES ( '"a","b","c","d"' );
INSERT INTO table_name (list) VALUES ( '"noquotes","\"quotes\"","comma,here"' );
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| noquotes |
| "quotes" |
| comma,here |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vbOXF3Go)

---

If your data is CSV compatible (where quotes in string literals are escaped by doubling them up and literals are separated with commas, but could be any delimiter) then you can use a recursive sub-query and regular expressions:

```sql
WITH matches (list, match, epos) AS (
  SELECT list,
         REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(list, '"(([^"]|"")+)"(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1), '""', '"'),
         REGEXP_INSTR(list, '"(([^"]|"")+)"(,|$)', 1, 1, 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT list,
         REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(list, '"(([^"]|"")+)"(,|$)', epos, 1, NULL, 1), '""', '"'),
         REGEXP_INSTR(list, '"(([^"]|"")+)"(,|$)', epos, 1, 1)
  FROM   matches
  WHERE  epos > 0
  AND    epos < LENGTH(list)
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY list SET order_id
SELECT match
FROM   matches
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(list VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO table_name (list) VALUES ( '"a","b","c","d"' );
INSERT INTO table_name (list) VALUES ( '"noquotes","""quotes""","comma,here"' );
```

Outputs:

| MATCH |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| noquotes |
| "quotes" |
| comma,here |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_NZF5I7q)

Answer (score -1):

If the delimiter is used inside the tokens to be separated, it's no more a delimiter, you will be able to separate the strings only if you have a way to escape the delimiter inside the tokens or quote the tokens containing the delimiter:
`a;b\;c;d`  or `a;"b;c",d` but `a;b;c;d` is forever ambiguous.